# Angular, connect function nested within child directive (few levels down) to parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a function I want to pass to a parent most controller to use - I have a directive inside a directive inside a directive (Directiveception) that will fire the function. I do not have liberty to turn this into one directive instead a directive with 2 nested ones so I'm wondering if there is a simpler/better way to do it than the way I'm thinking it will work.

So I have the outer most directive (these are restricted by class)

```
<div class="builder-result-filters" filter-obj="filterModelInstance" update-filter="filterClicked"> </div>
```

And then the one inside of that

```
<div>
<ul ng-repeat="filter in filterObj.filters" class="builder-result-single-filter" filter="filter">
</ul>
```

Then inside of that

```
  <ul>{{filter.name}}
<li ng-repeat="item in filter.values track by $index" class="build-result-filter-value" val="item">

</li>
```

Then lastly

```
 <li>
<input type="checkbox"  ng-change="filterChange()" ng-model="val.checked">  {{val.name}}
```

And what I'm trying to accomplish here is getting the ng-change="filterChange()", to fire in the top most directive. My intial thought is I would have to pass it down each level via the isolate scope like

```
 scope : {
       passedFunction: '=' //pass the function down to the bottom directive
  }
```

But I'm wondering if I can forgo having to do this on every level, or if there is a simpler solution. Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: You should throw this up into a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/). :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution you are looking for is `require`. It is described under "Creating Directives that Communicate" in the official [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Basically what you are doing is to access the controller of the top directive within an arbitrary directive down the stack (for example `bot`)

```
<top>
  <mid>
    <bot>     
    </bot>
  </mid>
</top>
```

In the code of the bottom directive you do the wiring with `require` and the name of the top directive

```
.directive('top', ... )
// ...
.directive('bot', function() {
  return {
    require: '^top',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      // ...
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, topCtrl) {
      scope.onClick = function() {
        topCtrl.doSomething("from bot");
      }
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="onClick()">Click Bot</button>'
  };
```

Here is the whole [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DjmVb7aKD5VphKprZXlL?p=preview) in Plunkr

Comment: I am using external controllers in this case, how would I pass topCtrl into it in this case? Thanks!

Comment: External controllers in the sense of that your top controller function gets invoked in some `module.controller` of the bottom directive? It would be really nice if you posted some code. But from my point of view I'd suggest to move the function declaration that invokes the top directive function to `link` of your bottom directive. That is, according to the docs, the best practice for directive communication.

Answer (score 0):

use **require** in your leaf directive to require the root directive.
Then a reference to the root directive will be passed in as a reference in your leaf directive's linking function.
Now you can call root.filterChange() in the leaf directive.

You can also $scope.$parent.$parent.. back from the leaf directive's $scope to get hold on the root directive's $scope and its filterChange function.